# How to get % of Parallel.ForEach completion

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I have some process that iterates over a group of large files in order and extracts information from them to write\update our databases. These files regularly have several thousand lines in each so I have built a Parallel.ForEach to process multiple lines concurrently in a given file(Only processing one file at a time due to needing to apply each file in order). Now I have a need to know approximately how much of the current file has been handled so that I can give management an indication of remaining runtime. So far I have the following

```
public void MyProcess(FileItem file)
{
    List<string> lines = file.GetLines(); //some process to get the lines to handle
    long cntr = 0; //The counter to track

    Parallel.ForEach(lines, crntLine =>
    {
       Console.Writeline(String.Format("Currently finished {0} out of {1} lines",cntr,lines.Count());
       InterLocked.Increment(ref cntr);

       //...Code to process crntLine here

    });
}
```

I don't care at all about which lines have been processed, only how many total so that can answer the question of how far along it is in the current file. Is this going to give me what I'm looking for reliably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs86dyzy(v=vs.110).aspx) will safely increment your counter as an atomic operation.

However, if you want a count of lines *completed*, you need to increment it after the line processing, not before:

```
public void MyProcess(FileItem file)
{
    List<string> lines = file.GetLines(); //some process to get the lines to handle
    long cntr = 0; //The counter to track

    Parallel.ForEach(lines, crntLine =>
    {
       //...Code to process crntLine here

       InterLocked.Increment(ref cntr);
       Console.Writeline(String.Format("Currently finished {0} out of {1} lines",cntr,lines.Count());
    });
}
```

If you want the percentage, divide the count completed by the total count, then multiply by 100:

```
double percentage = (double)cntr / lines.Count * 100
```

Comment: It seems I can't accept the answer for 5 more minutes, but this gave me what I need. Thank you!

Comment: I'm hitting a snag. I do need the percentage, but that answer appears to always be "0.00%" when I do it the way you have suggested. Here's the actual line of code i'm using `double percentDone = (lineCount / results.Count()) * 100;` What's going on?

Comment: @Rocky It's `cntr * 100 / lines.Count`

Comment: @Rabban That's just a different way of writing the equation. The mathematical output is the same. The problem is that in the code, the output is always 0. Maybe because lines.count and cntr are `integer` and `long` it doesn't want to give a `double` result or something.

Comment: @Rocky you are right, my comment was a little bit overhasty ;)

Comment: @Rocky Is that line in your comment working for you, or not?

Comment: @horns it is now, I just had to change it to `double percentDone = ((double)lineCount / (double)results.Count()) * 100;` so that the division would be double and not integer division.

Comment: @Rocky Good point, I'll add it to my answer. You should only need a cast on one of the numbers

Comment: @Rabban order of operations matter when doing integer division, doing `cntr * 100 / lines.Count` will give a diffrent result than `cntr / lines.Count * 100` because when you divide a int by a int it throws away the remainder, so you want that throw away to happen after the * 100 instead of before. However you still would not get any decimal points, so casting to a double is the better option if you want the decimal portion.